# find Url among text and erase it in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

What I need to do is:

1. Find the url text inside long text field.
2. Cut the url from the text.
3. Update the text field with the new value.

So far I can find the Url inside long text with the following code:

```
SELECT colomname FROM tablename
 WHERE colomname REGEXP "(https?:\/\/|www\.)[\.A-Za-z0-9\-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}"
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all in the `SELECT` query instead of selecting only columnname that holds the text, select also the id of the record. You can use the query result and loop over it in php. And in the loop you will do:

```
foreach ($data as $item) {
    $text = preg_replace('/https?://|www.)[.A-Za-z0-9-]+.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}/', '', $item['columnname']);

    $pdoData = [':text' => $text, ':id' => $id];
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('UPDATE table SET columnname=:text WHERE id=:id');
    $stmt->execute($pdoData);
}
```